# Shiny with plotly

Tags: r, timestamp, shiny, rstudio, plotly

[image]I'm creating a notebook with shiny and i have found the following issue when using the add-on plotly:

```
Data_xts=Data_xts()  #this return a reactive data.frame. fm_timeseries is already formated as POSIXct and has the following format : YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
plot_ly(x=Data_xts$fm_timeseries, y = Data_xts$Open,name='Stock Prices',showlegend = FALSE) %>%
add_trace(x=Data_xts$fm_timeseries, y = Data_xts$UKX_open, yaxis='y2') %>%
add_trace(x=Data_xts$fm_timeseries, y = Data_xts$TotalNews, yaxis='y3') %>%
layout(yaxis=list(title='Stock Price'),
yaxis2=list(title='Market Index', overlaying = "y",side='right',position=.97,tickfont = list(size = 8)), 
yaxis3=list(title='Total News', overlaying = "y",side='right',anchor='free', tickfont = list(size = 8),position=1),
xaxis=list(title='Time Series') , showlegend = TRUE)
```

Here is a couple of issues I'm founding:

- Time stamp don't show as timestamp (I even tried the simple example from plotly and R and verified that it doesn't work on Shiny). In fact timestamp is categorize as string and the xaxis tittle can't be seen as a result of this.
- Challenges getting the yaxis2 and 3 in the same axes without overlapping with the chart itself.

To solve this wonder if there is a format that we can pass into the xaxis (tried `type='date'` but didn't work) and if there is any type of auto-arrange on the yaxis on the right (2 and 3).

Comment: Modify the margins, as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726146/how-do-you-increase-the-space-between-the-axis-labels-and-axis-titles-in-r-using/40771909#40771909

Answer (score 0):

Try using "factor".
So in your example:

```
plot_ly(x= ~factor(Data_xts$fm_timeseries), y = ~Data_xts$Open, name='Stock Prices',showlegend = FALSE)
```