# How do you increase the space between the axis labels and axis titles in R using functions ggplot() and plot_ly?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly

It appears that whenever I create graphs in R using the package `plotly`, the axis titles always cover the axis labels. I have 2 graphs now where this occurs. What code should I use to increase the space between the axis titles and labels using `plot_ly()` and `ggplot()`? And how do I ensure that the legend is visible in Plot 1 and not cut off?

Previous StackOverflow questions give different ways to structure code but they just dont seem to work for my code.

Plot 1:

`plot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=HeightUnderCWD, y=GrassHeight))+ geom_point()+
    labs(x = "Height under CWD (cm)", y = "Grass Height (cm)")+
    theme(text=element_text(size=20, family="Arial"))+
    stat_smooth(method = "lm",formula = y ~ x,se = FALSE, color='Darkgreen')+
    stat_smooth(aes(x = HeightUnderCWD, y = 7, linetype = "Linear Fit"), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE,size = 1,color='lightgreen')
ggplotly(plot)`

[image]

Plot 2:

`p<-plot_ly(y = GrassHeight+1, color = CWDPosition,type = "box",colors = "Set1")%>%
    layout(xaxis = x, yaxis = y, font = f)`

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the links to these "previous StackOverflow questions" ? I don"t find them. In particular, the code for your second plot is incomplete (`x` and `y` in `layout(...)` should be some lists, but they are not given in your post).

Comment: Here's a link to a very related question for which I provided an answer (or "hacky workaround" as one might call it :p): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229013/plotly-r-setting-the-spacing-between-axis-label-and-axis-ticks-labels/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `plot_ly`, not sure it's the best answer, but it could be due to a too small left margin :

```
plot_ly(type="box") %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l=25, r=50, b=50, t=50, pad=0),
         yaxis=list(title="GrassHeight")) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 0)) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 1))
```

[image]

```
plot_ly(type="box") %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l=100, r=50, b=50, t=50, pad=0),
         yaxis=list(title="GrassHeight")) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 0)) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This does only increase the spacing to a certain (not very big) degree. To further manipulate the distance see [my answer to a very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47381330/7196903)