# Plotly R: setting the spacing between axis label and axis ticks labels

Tags: r, plotly

Is there any way to set a spacing between axis labels and axis ticks labels other than changing margins?

Example plot:

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ paste0(hp, '0000'))
```

As in the example plot above the title of the y axis is overlapping tick labels of this axis. Is there a way to set a spacing between them?

Comment: For others seeing this, the only thing that worked was the standoff answer and margin answer in conjunction.

Answer (score 20):

## Recommended solution

Since [plotly v4.9.2](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/NEWS.md#492) you can use the new [`standoff` layout attribute](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-title-standoff) which

> Sets the standoff distance (in px) between the axis labels and the title text The default value is a function of the axis tick labels, the title `font.size` and the axis `linewidth`. Note that the axis title position is always constrained within the margins, so the actual standoff distance is always less than the set or default value. By setting `standoff` and turning on `automargin`, plotly.js will push the margins to fit the axis title at given standoff distance.

Example:

```r
plotly::plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ paste0(hp, '0000')) %>%
  plotly::layout(yaxis = list(title = list(text = "Gross horsepower",
                                           standoff = 40L)))
```

[image]

---

## Obsolete Workaround

### Problem

Increasing the left margin [as @Codutie suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43229297/7196903) does help to a certain degree only (at least in plotly v4.7.1+). Most of the 150 pixel margin on the left is wasted space as can be seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

R-code to generate the above plot (from @Codutie):

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ paste0(hp, '0000')) %>%
  layout(margin = list(l = 150, r = 20, b = 10, t = 10))
```

Due to Plotly's goal of being responsive, it does a lot of the layout scaling automatically – which generally is a good thing IMHO because you don't have to fiddle around too much to get a presentable chart. Of course the results of Plotly's autoscaling aren't always perfect or exactly what you want to achieve and that's why [there are plenty of dedicated (layout) attributes](https://plot.ly/r/reference/) letting you manipulate certain aspects of your plot. **Unfortunately there's no attribute to set the distance between an axis label and the axis itself** (or the axis tick labels).

### Solution (Workaround)

Instead you can rely on **the following workaround** to manipulate the distance between the axis and it's label by setting an appropriate y-axis title string:

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ paste0(hp, '0000')) %>%
    layout(margin = list(l = 150, r = 20, b = 10, t = 10),
           yaxis = list(title = paste0(c(rep("&nbsp;", 20),
                                         "Gross horsepower",
                                         rep("&nbsp;", 20),
                                         rep("\n&nbsp;", 3)),
                                       collapse = "")))
```

This results in:
[image]

Explanation of the y-axis title components:

- `rep("\n&nbsp;", 3)`: This is the main part of the trick to increase the distance – just suffix the actual title (`"Gross horsepower"`) with newlines and non-breaking spaces.
- `rep("&nbsp;", 20)`: This is an additional measure to ensure Plotly's autoscaling doesn't interfere again – wrapping the actual title in 40 non-breaking spaces (could be more/less of course). Otherwise the text *Gross horsepower* would be placed in between two axis ticks as soon as the plot height gets large enough to "physically" allow it – which would kinda foil our attempt to manually set the distance because we would have to use a much bigger newline-non-breaking-space combo to get the same distance again and – more importantly – the distance would depend on the plot height. In the above plot this isn't really necessary though, because there are as much y-axis ticks that you would need to display the plot with a height way beyond 1000px to reach that critical point.

Comment: Thanks, `standoff` is just what I needed, for others who find this, you can pipe the output of `ggplotly()` to `layout()` to change the `standoff` value, it will print a new title though, so you'll have to do e.g., `theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())` to turn off the original one.

Answer (score 5):

Use the **`standoff`** option

```
library(plotly)

y <- list(
  title = list(text="Y Axis",standoff=20)
)

plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ paste0(hp, '0000'))%>%layout(yaxis=y)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try to modify the margins by adding them to your graph like this:

```
m <- list(l=150, r=20, b=10, t=10) # l = left; r = right; t = top; b = bottom
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~ wt, y = ~ paste0(hp, '0000')) %>% layout(margin=m)
```

hope this helps?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wanted to avoid doing it like that. I'm looking for a way to make it kind of automatic, so I don't need to adjust margins for every plot.

Comment: @r4ndomw4lk You could just write a function which adds the left margin (or even a custom title increasing the distance as [in my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47381330/7196903)) to automate things, no?

Like `add_margin <- function(plotly_object) { plotly_object %>% layout(margin = list(l = 60)) }`

Answer (score 3):

What I typically do is make use of the ticksuffix option which can create additional space behind a label.

```
layout(
      xaxis = list(title = "", automargin=T, ticksuffix = "%")
     ,yaxis = list(title = "", automargin=T, ticksuffix = "   ")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I dealt with this in Python was to simply add a line break and then whitespace and you can essentially have a blank line that creates the separation. Hacky, but it works. You can see it in the second line.

```
 yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(
    title_text="<b>Number of Articles<br> </b>",
    titlefont=dict(size=12)),
    paper_bgcolor="white",
    title=go.layout.Title(
    xref="paper",
    x=0.5 
  )
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

Comment: the question is asking how to do this in R. As far as I can tell this is unrelated. I tried some stuff similar to what you did in R and it does not solve the issue.